# How do I prevent MS Office from adding shortcuts (Word, Excel, PowerPoint) to the desktop?

Tags: windows-7, windows, microsoft-office, shortcuts, desktop

For efficiency, I keep only current work on my desktop. MS Office will add 3 shortcuts (Word, Excel, PowerPoint) everyday, several times a day: I deleted them, it adds them back. Is there a setting I can tweak to stop this from occurring?

Comment: Is this your personal computer or is it managed by your company?

Comment: This is my work computer, run by the university I work for. The problem started when they upgraded me to Office 2016, but I'm still using Windows 7. I have admin privileges. Thanks, Stephanie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd check with Microsoft's support for a way to actually make them stop doing this, but if this happens even when you don't have any Office application open then there is a workaround that might work: change the permissions of your Desktop folder so that only **your** user has write access.

Services and background processes are usually run by system users (e.g. `SYSTEM`, `LOCAL_SERVICE`), so this should stop them from writing to your Desktop folder, thus preventing the creation of these unwanted shortcuts.

Note that there is also an "all users" desktop folder under `%PUBLIC%\Desktop`, so you may have to do the same there. At first I thought to ask you if there are shortcuts there, but since you say you delete them and they go away, I'm guessing that's not it.

If this only happens when you have an Office application open, though, then this idea won't work, since you run them from your own user.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I will give it a try and let you know if it works. Thanks so much, Stephanie

Comment: It worked! Thanks so much for solving a seemingly simple problem that none of my friends in the IT department knew how to solve. Now I can teach them something :) Again thanks for your help. Best, Stephanie

Comment: Glad to be of help, Stephanie. =)
So if the problem's been solved then please close the question by accepting the answer.